# How to remove box/arrow next to image in web browser?

Tags: image, browser, web

How can I get rid of the little box/arrow next to images in my web browser? What controls when they show up and when they don't? I'm porting a blog from WordPress over to BlogEngine.NET. Those little arrows aren't in the WordPress blog, but they're showing up in the posts in BlogEngine.NET. I'm viewing both in Chrome. They also show up in IE and Firefox, but not in Safari.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Here are some live links (I'm viewing in Chrome):

WordPress (no arrow): http://www.inrixtraffic.com/blog/2012/neverlate-inrix-traffic-contest/

BlogEngine.NET (arrow): http://www.inrix.com/traffic/blog/post/2012/06/18/NeverLate-INRIX-Traffic-Contest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is coming from the CSS, specifically this selector:

```
div.post .text a[href^="http:"] {
    background: url(../../pics/remote.gif) right top no-repeat;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

According to my inspector (built into Chrome, right click, inspect element), that is coming from http://www.inrix.com/traffic/blog/themes/Inrix/style.css, line 372.  Ditch the "background" line from that file, or override it in a later css file, and you will be golden.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! (And thanks for the right click->inspect element tip!)